# Android: background image stretched vertically when PagerSlidingTabStrip is visible

Tags: android, android-viewpager, pagerslidingtabstrip

I'm using PagerSlidingTabStrip and ViewPager for slide tabs view. The pager contains two fragments(two tabs). I have set a background image of the fragment, and image fills full screen size when tabs are invisible. However, when the tabs are visible, the background image stretches vertically, which is unwanted (because the spaces taken by tab, so the background image is stretched). The width of the background image is not changed.

Is there a way not to stretch the background image vertically or stretch it same width and height at same scale?

tab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_views_default"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/strip_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        app:pstsShouldExpand="true"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: After digging into this, I realize that this issue happens because the background image is set in the fragments, which are contained in view pager. So when the fragment are loaded, the background is stretched vertically because the tabs at top takes some room. Even when I set the background image in viewpager again, it is still the same case. I guess image of viewpager is covered by image of fragment. At this stage, I have to set the background image in fragment because it is used by other component as well.

Comment: Still cannot figure out how to make the background image not stretched if the image is set in the fragment contained in viewpager, while using PagerSlidingTabStrip. Right now, I have to set the background image in the viewpager instead of fragment. So for other components, I have to create a new fragment instead of using the common one because the background image is not set in there anymore.

Comment: Finally, I have a solution. In my adapter (which extends FragmentPagerAdapter), I override the finishUpdate() method, so the background image of each fragment can be remove. And set a background image in viewpager so all fragment can share one static background image.

public void finishUpdate(ViewGroup container) {
  super.finishUpdate(container);
  //remove background image for all fragments
 }
}